# How to convert PGN moves to long algebraic notation (in python)?

Tags: programming, pgn, python

I want to read a PGN file and then advance to a certain move number, and feed that to an UCI engine.  Turns out engines work using long algebraic notation, and PGNs are in short algebraic.  What is an easy way to make the conversion?  i.e. from SAN to LAN.

I realize that generating long algebraic notation requires knowledge of the board state & chess rules, so I don't want to write it all again!  Surely something like this must already exist - either a command line program or a module (preferably in python).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming, not about chess.

Comment: AFAIK, the most explicit meta discussion there's been that's pertinent to whether this is on-topic is http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/q/100/167. The consensus at that point seemed to be that something like this should be considered on-topic. (Note: I'm not arguing one way or the other, so don't take it up with me. But do feel free to contribute to that meta thread.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Would this be what you are looking for? **PGN-extract** (A command line utility)
http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/djb/pgn-extract/

I can see a flag in the [feature doc](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/djb/pgn-extract/help.html) that might help:

- `-W[cm|epd|halg|lalg|elalg|san|uci]` - specify the output format to use
  `-Whalg` is hyphenated long algebraic.
  `-Wlalg` is long algebraic
  `-Welalg[PNBRQK]` is enhanced long algebraic. Use the characters PNBRQK for language

Comment: The best option for the person who asked is probably `-Wuci` if they want to feed it to an UCI engine.